# Remove Custom Nav Bar on Email Sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have this code in my App Delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav Bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works great, but I use the `MFMailComposeViewController` and I want it to have the default NavigationBar appearance.

How do I do that?

EDIT:

I tried this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn: [MFMailComposeViewController class], [UIViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Textured Background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I've also tried having only this code. Nothing changes. Default Nav bar, including with the Mail View Controller.

I think it could be something with the `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`. Does anyone know what `MFMailComposeViewController` would be contained in?

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out! Here's the code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
MFMailComposeViewController *emailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
//the rest of the implementation goes here...
[self presentViewController:emailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, I set the nav bar appearance back to normal here:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav Bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: it does not work to me.. the image in my appearance it is always showed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn: [MFMailComposeViewController class], nil]
```

Which means all navigation bars contained in a MFMailComposeViewController class

From the docs: [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

This will return the appearance proxy so you can modify it like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn: [MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:myImage];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Didn't work. Here's my code: `[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn: [MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mail Nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` The `Mail Nav.png` is a transparent image, so it should just show the normal nav bar.

Comment: @Cody I do no think you can revert it to the "normal" nav bar, the normal bar is internally also setting a background image (or a tint color not sure), so once it is changed you cannot revert it. You have to essentially reproduce the background image it is using.

Comment: I think it could be something with the `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`. Do you know what `MFMailComposeViewController` would be contained in?